# "detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed." django rest framework

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am new to django so having issues with it. Post method is not allowed.
I have shared below both views.py and urls.py.
Please help me out with it.

```
    views.py

    from django.shortcuts import render
    from rest_framework import viewsets,generics
    from user.serializer import UserSerializer,RetailerSerializer,ProductSerializer,Order_ItemsSerializer,Payment_DetailsSerializer,Order_DetailsSerializer
    from user.models import User,Retailer,Product,Order_Items,Payment_Details,Order_Details
    from product.models import Cart,Shipping_Address,Track_Repairs,NFT_Details
    from product.serializer import CartSerializer,Shipping_AddressSerializer,Track_RepairsSerializer,NFT_DetailsSerializer
    
    
    class AddProduct(generics.CreateAPIView):
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    class Product_List(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Product.objects.all().order_by('name')
        serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    class Product_Detail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
        queryset = Product.objects.all().order_by('name')
        serializer_class = ProductSerializer

urls.py

from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'',views.Product_List)

urlpatterns = [
    path('product/',include(router.urls)),
    path('product/<int:pk>/',views.Product_Detail.as_view()),
    path("product/add/", views.AddProduct.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: on which url are you getting this error?

Comment: I have to do it for AddProducts. It shows issue in product/add.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to use post method in Product_List viewset you can specify allowed http methods:

Ex:

```
    class Product_List(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Product.objects.all().order_by('name')
        serializer_class = ProductSerializer
        http_method_names = ["post"]
```

To allow multiple http methods:

```
class Product_List(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Product.objects.all().order_by('name')
        serializer_class = ProductSerializer
        http_method_names = ["get","post"]
```

Comment: I have to do it for AddProducts. It shows issue in product/add.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the similar error but I was making calls to wrong url. For example I was making call to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/` rather than `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/api/` (bad naming I know) as this is how I have configured api related urls from another directory. Are you sure you are not making a similar mistake?